# Mechanics of book falling on it's side

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I have the following question that I'm struggling with.

Imagine you have a very thin book (we consider it's thickness to be 0) that sits upright.  At some point the book falls to it's side. How can we describe the motion of the book?

How would friction between the book and the table affect the outcome? Can we use conservation of energy?

I think we can use the fact that torque is equal to the derivative of angular momentum with respect to time, but I don't know how to write the forces. We obviously have gravity, but how would the reactive force work in this case? Is this right:

$$\vec{R} = \vec{T} + \vec{N} \ ?$$
This would mean that $\vec{N}$ goes to $0$ as the book falls. Is this correct?

Would it be possible to express the angle $\alpha$ and the position $x_{C_m}$ of the center of mass in terms of time?
[image: diagram of problem]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would the angular velocity of the rod change if it slipped on the table?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215461/how-would-the-angular-velocity-of-the-rod-change-if-it-slipped-on-the-table)

Comment: Thanks @DavidBailey, This link is very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that friction is always sufficient to prevent the book from slipping at O then you can take moments about O, which allows you to ignore the forces acting through O itself. The only force acting on the book that does not go though O is its weight W, so you have

$\displaystyle W \frac {|\vec{OB}|}{2} \sin \alpha = I \frac {d^2 \alpha} {dt^2}$

where $I$ is the book's moment of inertia about an axis through O. Essentially, you have a rod pivoted at O. The motion of the book is determined if you have initial values for $\alpha$ and $\frac {d\alpha}{dt}$.

If friction is not always sufficient to prevent the book from slipping then the problem becomes more complex, and you probably have to divide the motion into two parts, before slipping and after slipping, which will have different equations of motion.

Comment: Thanks, @gandalf61, That makes sense, but I still have a couple of questions. First of all, are the N and T forces on my diagram correctly represented? And if the friction is 0, in which direction will the book slip?

Comment: @phys1643 Yes, the normal force is vertically upwards and friction acts to the right. If there is no friction then the bottom of the book will move to the left.

Comment: Is the T component of the reactive force also correctly represented? @gandalf61

Comment: @phys1643 I assumed T was friction. The table or ground that the book rests on can only exert a normal force perpendicular to itself, which is N. There is no horizontal component of the normal force. If there is no friction then T is zero.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So in this case the friction force would be the usual F = _u_ N, where _u_  is the friction coefficient and N = G cos(\alpha) ?